# How to create a download link for files in docusaurus?

Tags: html, markdown, docusaurus

I tried to create a download link in docusaurus and it only works when I am in dev mode. When I create the build, the links don't work at all. I tried to put it like this example:
`[JSON dataset](pathname://linktofile.json)`  or  `<a target="_blank" href="pathname://file.json" download="file.json">Download</a>`

It works fine on local server but when I do,
`npm run build` and `npm run serve`
It doesnt work. It fails to make a downloadable file.

Comment: I tried here, and could not make it work with `json`… But if you zip it, like `file.zip`, then it works.

Comment: i'll give it a shot thanks!